# how to manipulate jtextfield return type?

Tags: java, swing, document, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

I have a jtext field

when user type a number like

> 123456789,10

it will automatic set in jtextfield

> 123,456,789.10

then if user click a button it will

System.out.print( the_same_number );

that will result

> 123456789.10

- how to do this?
- how to make jtextfield only accept input number and dot (.) and coma (,)?

(should i use formatted field in this case?)

thanks..

Comment: *"i have a jtext field"*  Do you have a shift key on the keyboard?  If so, please use it for the start of sentences and for J2SE class names etc.

Comment: So, you want to change the comma to a decimal, and then add comma separators? Do you want this to happen as the user is typing, or when the user finishes and exits the JTextField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use a [`DocumentFilter`](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) to filter the input coming into the text field.

Check out [MDP's Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) which actually has an example of the question you are asking

Comment: thanks.. i do exactly your answer.. but i confuse.. chosing documentfilter or plaindocument ... what should i choose? what different of it? thanks ..

Comment: Essentially, you can apply a `DocumentFilter` to any `AbstractDocument` that includes `JTextField`, `JTextArea`, `JTextPane` and `JTextEditor` (just to name a few), where as the `PlainDocument` is an implementation of the `Document` interface for use with plain text (such as `JTextField` and `JTextArea`)

Comment: implementation of the Document interface for use with plain text ... ok.. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can opt for the `DocumentFilter` as suggested by @MadProgrammer. However, it will be difficult to tackle the requirement to have a different display in the text field and when printing to console (it will require some extra manual parsing/formatting).

Combined with the requirement to accept only numbers I would strongly suggest to look at the `JFormattedTextField` in combination with a `NumberFormat`.

- The `JFormattedTextField` will only accept input that can be parsed by the `NumberFormat` (you can type invalid input, but it will never be accepted)
- The actual value (`JFormattedTextField#getValue`) will be a `Double` (if you choose the correct format), so you can print it perfectly

Note that the standard `JFormattedTextField` has some usability issues. With a bit of googling you can find different improved version of the `JFormattedTextField`. For example [this one](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/formatted-text-field-tips/) where I find the only missing thing is visual feedback when the input is invalid (e.g. make the background red)

Comment: thanks it will helpfull .. yeah its difficult play with documentfilter.. i use many string format.. it took me 2 days without sleep.. ~_~" .. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

"how to make jtextfield only accept input number and dot (.) and coma (,)?"

```
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if ((e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57) || e.KeyChar == 46 || e.KeyChar == 44){
        }
        else{
        }
    }
```

Comment: DO NOT use `KeyListeners` to filter input into any `JTextComponent`, the order of key events is undefined and will cause document mutation exceptions.  You are better of using a `DocumentFilter` - `KeyListeners` also do not take into account things like the user pasting text into the field or the programmer call `setText`